# Laravel Test Inaccurate Result

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am testing my api routes in my laravel app, and I struggle why laravel test always inaccurate. To simulate 404 status code, I created a test with non existing route, but it always returns 200 status code.

```
 public function testTicketsLists()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    $response = $this->actingAs($user, 'web')->withSession(['foo' => 'bar'])->get("api/{$this->endpoint}/ticketss");
    $response
        ->assertStatus(404);
    // $response->dump();
}


 Expected status code 404 but received 200. Failed asserting that 404 is identical to 200.
```

The `ticketss` endpoint is does not exists so I expected a 404 status code

api.php

```
   /*
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| services
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
// get all client api methods
Route::get('services/methods', 'Api\ServicesController@methods');
// get service lists
Route::get('services/lists', 'Api\ServicesController@serviceLists');
// get service details by id per client 
Route::get('services/{id}/details', 'Api\ServicesController@details');
// all service ids
Route::get('services/serviceids', 'Api\ServicesController@serviceids');
/*
```

Update, I did some debugging, now I understand why it doesn't return 404 response

```
    Illuminate\Testing\TestResponse^ {#8672
    +baseResponse: Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse^ {#7923
#data: "{"message":"Page Not Found","status":404,"error":true}"
#callback: null
#encodingOptions: 0
+headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag^ {#7924
  #computedCacheControl: array:2 [
    "no-cache" => true
    "private" => true
  ]
  #cookies: []
  #headerNames: array:5 [
    "cache-control" => "Cache-Control"
    "date" => "Date"
    "content-type" => "Content-Type"
    "x-ratelimit-limit" => "X-RateLimit-Limit"
    "x-ratelimit-remaining" => "X-RateLimit-Remaining"
  ]
  #headers: array:5 [
    "cache-control" => array:1 [
      0 => "no-cache, private"
    ]
    "date" => array:1 [
      0 => "Thu, 27 Aug 2020 06:38:52 GMT"
    ]
    "content-type" => array:1 [
      0 => "application/json"
    ]
    "x-ratelimit-limit" => array:1 [
      0 => 60
    ]
    "x-ratelimit-remaining" => array:1 [
      0 => 59
    ]
  ]
  #cacheControl: []
}
#content: "{"message":"Page Not Found","status":404,"error":true}"
#version: "1.1"
#statusCode: 200
#statusText: "OK"
#charset: null
+original: array:3 [
  "message" => "Page Not Found"
  "status" => 404
  "error" => true
]
+exception: null
}
#streamedContent: null
}
```

The statusCode is always 200, how can I properly test in this scenario ?

Comment: u should include your routes as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after minutes of debugging, I change the assertions to this

```
   $response->assertJson([
        'status' => 404
    ]);
```

Then I got the expected result.